# MS Access Combo Box Row Source: Looking to get values from a table but also add a single value that is not in the table

Tags: ms-access

I have a combo box on one of my forms.  I would like the row source to pull from a field in a table that I have.  I have that working fine.  However, I would like to add one value that would not be in the table itself.  So basically I am looking to offer all of the values in the table field plus one that I would not have to add to the table.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do both. but you can modify the underlying query to append that one value you want included in a union

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM yourtable
union all
select top 1 'x','y' 
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean?  I do not want to store the value anywhere in a table other than the one that the combo box populates.  For instance I have a table with all of our subsidiaries abbreviations in it.  I want to pull all of those values as options for the combo box, but I also want to be able to add "Vendor" as one of the choices without having to pull the value "Vendor" from a table.

Comment: That is exactly what the example i provided does. You are not modifying the underlying table, a union all jusy brings the results together from more than one query. In this case, the first part should be your query as is now, and second part is again pointing at the same query, however only selects a single row from it. And instead of returning a column from the table, you put the value you want 'vendor' in qoutes. If you still have trouble post the query, or table that the combo box reads, and also wn the static value you want to include